# onclick i want it to change the value of the button to the random string in the array

Tags: javascript

```
function randomize(){
    var maps =["Aztec","Cache","Cobblestone","Dust","DustII","Inferno",
    "Mirage","Nuke","Overpass","Train","Vertigo","Assault","Italy","Militia","Office,"];
    var randommap = maps[math.floor(math.random() * maps.lenth)];
    var randommap = document.getElementById("map").innerHTML = randommap;
    }
```

Comment: it will not change the buttons name to a random string from the array maps how do i do it?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very terse if not ill constructed question. Equally so here is a terse yet well constructed answer:

```js
var maps = ['Aztec', 'Cache', 'Cobblestone', 'Dust',
  'DustII', 'Inferno', 'Mirage', 'Nuke', 'Overpass',
  'Train', 'Vertigo', 'Assault', 'Italy', 'Militia',
  'Office'];

function randomItem(list) {
  var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length);
  return list[randomIndex];
}

var mapEl = document.getElementById('map');

mapEl.onclick = function() {
  mapEl.innerHTML = randomItem(maps);
};
```

```html
<button id="map">Go!</button>
```

Comment: to add a tick box to the maps in the array would i need to append the array?

Comment: What's a tick box? Your question was "how to pick a random element from an array?"

Comment: I have worked some more(a little more im new to js)i have had problems with the button element not working can you tell me why?